# How to preserve state value after re-running setState

Tags: reactjs, object, setstate

setLabels is called every time a user clicks on a checkbox, resulting in a list of items that match the itemId that has been selected. (EX. if 1.3 is checked, the for loop runs through exportEntries, grabs all the objects values matching the key 1.3)

I then use setState to set filteredArray to the values returned. However, the next time a user clicks on another checkbox, the state is obviously reset.

How would I go about maintaining all previously selected values and adding to the state instead of replacing the current state set?

```
setLabels = (e, itemId, itemLabel) => {

    let fillerArray = [];
    for (let item of this.state.exportEntries) {

      if (itemId in item) {
        fillerArray.push({ [itemLabel]: item[itemId] });
      }  

      this.setState({
        filteredArray: fillerArray
      });

    }

    console.log(this.state.filteredArray);

    e.preventDefault();
  }
```

**On first Click Output**

```
0: {First: "One"}
1: {First: "Two"}
2: {First: "Three"}
3: {First: "Four"}
4: {First: "Five"}
```

**On second Click Output**

```
0: {Second: "One"}
1: {Second: "Two"}
2: {Second: "Three"}
3: {Second: "Four"}
4: {Second: "Five"}
```

** EDIT for Arrays of Objects **

```
  const singleValue = [...this.state.selectedValues];

  for (let item of this.state.exportEntries) {
    if (id in item) {

      // This is pulling values from exportEntries that match the id 
      // of the 'label' selected. So 'First', 'Last', etc... all have 
      // an id that is passed to perform the check here.
      singleValue.push({ [label]: item[id] });
    }
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < singleValue.length; i++) {
    merged.push({ ...this.state.selectedValues[i], ...singleValue[i]})
  }

  // This is where I'm trying to merge the two arrays
  // If I click First & Last this is returned: 

  // (10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
  //   0: {First: "First 1"}
  //   1: {First: "First 2"}
  //   2: {First: "First 3"}
  //   3: {First: "First 4"}
  //   4: {First: "First 5"}
  //   5: {Last: "Last 1"}
  //   6: {Last: "Last 2"}
  //   7: {Last: "Last 3"}
  //   8: {Last: "Last 4"}
  //   9: {Last: "Last 5"}

  // I want this:
  // (5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
  //   0: {First: "First 1" , Last: "Last 1"}
  //   1: {First: "First 2", Last: "Last 2"}
  //   2: {First: "First 3", Last: "Last 3"}
  //   3: {First: "First 4", Last: "Last 4"}
  //   4: {First: "First 5", Last: "Last 5"}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to run `setState` everytime in the loop and not afterwards when finished building the new array?

Comment: @Auskennfuchs i'll definitely be adjusting the structure to include this comment. However, I'll still need to preserve all the previous selections somehow. Is there anyway you could provide some documentation or example on how to preserve these values?

Comment: @SethSpivey would you be able to share codesandbox MVP?

Comment: @DipenShah this is all tied into pieces that require specific keys and is a part of a much more complicated project that would take too much time to create within a sandbox. I'll be more than happy to explain or provide any anything though.

Comment: @SethSpivey sure I added suggestion based on my understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am still having bit hard time understanding your question, but based on my best ability I am trying to suggest you something which might work.

I have created a [POC](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-chaplygin-s3tck) to get around this issue. Main issue is that you current state is updated asynchronously so accessing it immediately after update will not give you updated state.

In my example code, I have added bunch of checkboxes and `onChange` I am updating state to set all selected checkboxes and in the **callback** of `setSate` I am calling `setLabels` (which I still don't understand what it does).

Important thing here is to do processing after state is updated. Also, looking at your code two things standout in particular:

1. You are calling `this.setState({ filteredArray: fillerArray });` from inside of an array which is redundant and you just want to call it once.
2. You are updating fillerArray all the time with new value `let fillerArray = [];`, may be you want `let fillerArray = [...this.state.filteredArray];` to preserve old selection.

Take a look at this POC code:

```
class SomeClass extends Component {
  state = {
    selectedItems: [],
    exportEntries: [],
    filteredArray: []
  };

  setLabels = (itemId, itemLabel) => {
    console.log(this.state.selectedItems);
  };

  handleCheckBoxChange = (isSelected, id, label) => {
    const newSelection = [...this.state.selectedItems];
    if (isSelected) {
      newSelection.push(label);
    } else {
      const index = newSelection.indexOf(label);
      newSelection.splice(index, 1);
    }

    this.setState({ selectedItems: newSelection }, () =>
      this.setLabels(id, label)
    );
  };

  render = () => (
    <div>
      <label>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          onChange={(e) =>
            this.handleCheckBoxChange(e.target.checked, "name", "First")
          }
        />
        Item 1
      </label>
      <label>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          onChange={(e) =>
            this.handleCheckBoxChange(e.target.checked, "name", "Second")
          }
        />
        Item 2
      </label>
      <label>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          onChange={(e) =>
            this.handleCheckBoxChange(e.target.checked, "name", "Third")
          }
        />
        Item 3
      </label>
      <label>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          onChange={(e) =>
            this.handleCheckBoxChange(e.target.checked, "name", "Fourth")
          }
        />
        Item 4
      </label>
      <div>
        {this.state.selectedItems.map((i) => (
          <p>{i}</p>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: @SethSpivey did this help?

Comment: It has helped! I'm currently working on adding a few pieces that are more specific to the project and will mark it as soon as I have it completed!

Comment: Real quick, could you explain the this.setState({ selectedItems: newSelection }, () =>
      this.setLabels(id, label)
    );

Comment: Yes sure, so `setState` is asynchronous and when you run something after `setState` call which will access newState, there is no guarantee that new state will be applied by the time code runs so I added that as a callback to `setState` method which will ensure that, `this.setLabels` will only executed once `setState` is called and state update is completed. You can find more: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Comment: Okay. So, is there anyway I could pass another setState within this function as well?

Comment: You can use multiple updates within `setState` call to ensure those updates will be applied all at once.

Comment: Dipen, would you be willing to edit this answer to include how to perform a merging of arrays within handleCheckBoxChange?

Comment: Sure I will take a look bit later.

Comment: @SethSpivey could you elaborate bit more, by looking at question again I don't see any arrays, instead it is updating single item in state.

Comment: I've added edits to the question! Let me know if you have any more questions after reviewing that please.

Comment: @SethSpivey would you be able to update POC codesandbox, I shared because I am still confused to why would you want to merge two different objects in two different arrays, what if they have different length? How can you say for sure it will merge to `{First: "First 1" , Last: "Last 1"}` and not `{First: "First 1" , Last: "Last 4"}`?

Comment: I've updated the sandbox, let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Can you share the link? After update it will be forked to a different address.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-pike-joz3l?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Take a look at this: https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-cohen-cthx4, I have to update logic to merge.

Comment: You are a life saver. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your requirement correctly you want to toggle the checkboxes and keep a list of all checked items. You already have the `filteredArray`. In the `setLabel`method you have to add the current item, if it was checked or remove it from the list, if it was unchecked. The event should give you this information ( `e.checked` or something).

```js
class SomeClass extends Component {
   state = {
     filteredArray: []
   }

   setLabels = (e, itemId, itemLabel) => {
     const { filteredArray } = this.state
     if(e.checked) {
       this.setState({
          filteredArray: [...filteredArray,{[itemLabel]: item[itemId]}]
       })
     } else {
        this.setState({
           filteredArray: filteredArray.filter(item => item[itemLabel]===undefined)
        })
     }
     console.log(this.state.filteredArray);
 
     e.preventDefault();
   }   
}
```

If you could check the item in the event, it should not have been added to the array, so it will be appended. Otherwise it was already added and will be filtered out.
The filter looks a little bit strange. You have the `itemId`, which i presume is unique. So I would suggest, to add the `itemId` explicitly to the object to have a better filter criteria.
The code is not tested, but it should work in this way.

Also keep in mind the `console.log` will probably doesn't give you the correct output because `setState` is not synchronous.

Comment: Sorry, after implementing this item comes back as undefined in the else setState.